# Multidimensional arrays code results in "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am doing a project for school that deals with arrays and I have run into a problem. I was wondering if anybody could explain the error that I am getting. Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayPrinter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int [] oneD = {5, 6, 7, 8 }; 

        int[][] twoD = {{2, 4, 6, 8}, 
                        {8, 7, 9, 1}, 
                        {3, 5, 1, 2}};

        int[][] twoD2 = {{1, 2}, 
                         {3, 4, 5}, 
                         {6},
                         {7, 8, 9}}; 

        printArray(oneD);

        printArray(twoD);  

        System.out.println(" ");

        printArray(twoD2);
     }


    public static void printArray(int[] arr) {

        int size = arr.length;
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i=0;i< size; i++){
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
            if(i<size-1){
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

     public static void printArray(int[][] arr)
     {

          System.out.println("[ ");

          for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++){

                System.out.print("");

              for (int i = 0; row < arr[row].length; i++)
              {
                   printArray(arr[i]);

              }
               System.out.println("]");            

          }        
     }
}
```

I am getting an error when I run this in Eclipse. This is my output:

```
[5,6,7,8]

[

[2,4,6,8]

[8,7,9,1]

[3,5,1,2]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

at ArrayPrinter.printArray(ArrayPrinter.java:51)

at ArrayPrinter.main(ArrayPrinter.java:19)
```

How can I fix this error? And could you please explain why, rather that just do it for me?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; row < arr[row].length; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < arr[row].length; i++)`

Comment: and you should be using both indices like arr[row][i] for a 2D array instead of doing arr[i] which refers to 1D array

Comment: Did you look up anything about the exception? What part of the error message is confusing to you?

Comment: I switched it and I still get the same error message. Any other ideas? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: I don't know what the error means at all......and I do not know how to get rid of the error message. That is the part I am confused with. Also, this is not the finished project as I still have some steps I have to do but I want to fix the error before moving on.@takendarkk

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think about what you're doing in `printArray(int[][] arr)`:

```
for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++){
    ...
}
```

This loops over the rows of the array. Remember, all those rows are arrays. At this point, `arr[row]` has type `int[]`. You have a `printArray` function that accepts an `int[]`, so call that. The part where you loop over `i` is unnecessary.

Your `IndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when you try to access an element of an array that is out of bounds. For example:

```
int[] arr = {42};
arr[3] // IndexOutOfBoundsException! arr has length 1, so arr[3] is out of bounds
```

You are getting the error because you are trying to loop over `i`, but the condition for termination is `row < arr[row].length`. That means that on the first iteration `row` will be 0. It will enter the `i` loop, and it will check if `0 < twoD2[0].length` (it is) and then it will access `twoD2[i]`. Then it increments `i` and performs the check again, but `row` has not been updated! If a condition is true at the entry of a loop and you don't change the variables that are used in the condition, you will never exit the loop. Thus `i` never stops incrementing and eventually you try to access `twoD2[4]` and get the exception.

Comment: This makes total sense! Thank you very much for explaining! Now I know if that happens in the future! I have been trying to figure it out for three days now and posted here since it is my last thing I could try. Again, thank you a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code:

```
  System.out.println("[ ");
  for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
      System.out.print("");
      for (int i = 0; row < arr[row].length; i++) {
           printArray(arr[i]);
      }
      System.out.println("]");            
  }
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense. In your inner loop you are referencing `arr[i]` which is returning an `int[]` using the `i` index which ranges from 0 to `arr[row]`. In other words it's printing as many entire rows as there are elements in the current row. That is clearly not want you want.

In reality you don't need the inner loop at all. You already have a method that prints a `int[]` so you really just need to iterate through the rows.

```
  System.out.println("[ ");
  for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
      System.out.print("");
      printArray(arr[row]);
  }
  System.out.println("]");
```

Also note that a lot of your code could be simpler if you used a for-each loop:

```
for (int[] row: arr) {
    printArray(row);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The method for printing multidimensional array should look:

```
public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
     System.out.println("[ ");
     for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
         printArray(arr[row]);
     }
     System.out.println("]");
}
```

Comment: The user asked for an explanation of the error message.  This is not it.